# AWS S3 Folder deleted History

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there ways to get deleted history of AWS s3 bucket?

Problem Statement :
Some of s3 folders got deleted . Is there way to figure out when it got deleted

Answer (score 5):

There are at least two ways to accomplish what you want to do, but both are disabled by default.
The first one is to enable [server access logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) on your bucket(s), and the second one is to use [AWS CloudTrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html).

You might be out of luck if this already happened and you had no auditing set up, though.